# changing image file name rmagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

The Rmagick docs aren't the clearest, i've tried everything but it doesn't like it? Maybe im misunderstanding how Magick::Info works?

http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/info.html

```
def crop_photo(url, x, y, w, h)
 image =  Magick::ImageList.new
 urlimage = open(url)
 format = url.split('/')[-1].strip.split('?')[0].strip
 image.from_blob(urlimage.read)
 crop = image.crop(x,y,w,h)
 image = crop.to_blob
    image.filename = format #doesn't work
    self.filename = format  #doesn't work
end
```

help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save Image or ImageList you use `write` method:

`image.write(new_filename)`

Comment: to change filename i have to write?